# Output is getting converted to encoded form rather than remaining in input like string

Tags: python

I want to remove special characters like `,`,`!`,`.`,`*` from string. I am getting individual words stripped off the special characters. Remaining part of the string is being stored in a list.

```
zenPython = '''
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
'''
s= zenPython.split()
y=iter(s)
a=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(next(y).strip(',!*.'))
    a.append(y)
print(a)
```

loop is working fine. its print(a) that is printing results in `['<list_iterator object at 0x0000018EBCE9C6D8>', '<list_iterator object at 0x0000018EBCE9C6D8>'....]` format. I want output as [The,Zen,of,Python,by,Tim,Peters,Beautiful,is,better,than,...]

Comment: What do you mean here? You're not going to get `[The, Zen, of, ...]`, in the best case you'll get `['The', 'Zen', 'of', ...]` - because all of those things are strings. Could you be more explicit and specific on what inputs/outputs you're going for?

Comment: If you can run the code once in spyder, you will get the output. I am getting hexadecimal values which is not getting displayed in question. Those values are vanishing as soon as question is posted.

Comment: You are appending an iterator object `y` to the list instead of the actual string @Satyajeet See my answer below :)

Comment: The results in `['', ''....]` format are Python's default console representation of a list of strings. One of the reasons for this format is that the default representation is still actually executable Python code, whereas what you want isn't. No harm in that, but in that case you are expected to do the formatting by hand yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a iterator object while using `next()`.

Use:

```
zenPython = '''
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
'''
s= zenPython.split()
y=iter(s)
a=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    val = next(y).strip(',!*.')
    print(val)
    a.append(val)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using regular expressions you can do this

```
import re

""""
Pattern to Remove all special characters(and spaces) except the  
punctuation mark (’) that appear in contractions i.e aren't or it's
"""
non_special_characters = r"[A-Za-z0-9']+"

print(re.findall(non_special_characters,zenPython))
```

Note: I assumed that your text only contains ASCII characters,so, there are no problems with  words like Straße or Gesäß from german. I also assumed that you want to delete the character -  (like in --obvious), but if you want to keep it, just add it to non_special_characters.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you are appending the iterator object `y` to the list, instead of the actual string.

```
In [50]: type(y)                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[50]: list_iterator
```

If you want to use this approach, you would want to append `next(y)` to the list which actually gives you the string

```
s= zenPython.split()
y=iter(s)
a=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    a.append(next(y))
print(a)
```

Or you can use a list comprehension for iterating over the words, where you split words by whitespace, and strip the characters you want and create a new list out of it

```
#Split words by whitespace, and strip the characters you want
a= [ item.strip(',!*.') for item in zenPython.split()]
print(a)
```

The output will be

```
['The', 'Zen', 'of', 'Python', 'by', 'Tim', 'Peters', 'Beautiful', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'ugly', 'Explicit', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'implicit', 'Simple', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'complex', 'Complex', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'complicated', 'Flat', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'nested', 'Sparse', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'dense', 'Readability', 'counts', 'Special', 'cases', "aren't", 'special', 'enough', 'to', 'break', 'the', 'rules', 'Although', 'practicality', 'beats', 'purity', 'Errors', 'should', 'never', 'pass', 'silently', 'Unless', 'explicitly', 'silenced', 'In', 'the', 'face', 'of', 'ambiguity', 'refuse', 'the', 'temptation', 'to', 'guess', 'There', 'should', 'be', 'one--', 'and', 'preferably', 'only', 'one', '--obvious', 'way', 'to', 'do', 'it', 'Although', 'that', 'way', 'may', 'not', 'be', 'obvious', 'at', 'first', 'unless', "you're", 'Dutch', 'Now', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'never', 'Although', 'never', 'is', 'often', 'better', 'than', 'right', 'now', 'If', 'the', 'implementation', 'is', 'hard', 'to', 'explain', "it's", 'a', 'bad', 'idea', 'If', 'the', 'implementation', 'is', 'easy', 'to', 'explain', 'it', 'may', 'be', 'a', 'good', 'idea', 'Namespaces', 'are', 'one', 'honking', 'great', 'idea', '--', "let's", 'do', 'more', 'of', 'those']
```